# git on solaris 10

Tags: solaris, git

I would like to install git on a solaris 10 sparc 64 bit machine.
Is there a trustworthy repository for solaris packages (like git)?

I would like a binary package.

sunfreeware seems to cost money nowadays, and it is simply too difficult for me to go through purchase, for a simple try-out.

Edit: sunfreeware is still free. You have to click cancel before switching site.

Comment: sunfreeware is free.

Comment: Is this still a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look to [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/git/) or migrate to Solaris 11 which has git in its standard repository.
OpenCSW and Solaris 11 installers automatically handles dependencies unlike Sunfreeware packages.

Comment: This works really great. I managed to use it offline as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Sunfreeware](http://www.sunfreeware.com/indexsparc10.html) has a Sparc Solaris 10 version of [git-1.7.6](http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#git) that would install in /usr/local/bin.

Note that there are a whole bunch of dependencies and they may have dependencies too.

Comment: It lets you click a couple of times, before asking you to subscribe at a cost, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: @mirk: Just click cancel - sunfreeware is free - I just downloaded the git package and it's dependencies.

Comment: stupid me, you are right of course.

Comment: The Sunfreeware URL is throwing a 404.